# JNI GetObjectClass always returns new object of class?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I wan to know that in **jni**

```
jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, obj);
```

it returns **new object** or **current object** of class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the JVM. For example, on Android, classes are singletons, therefore GetObjectClass() returns the current instance, if the class has been loaded.